# How can Pythons mock library test a function is called with bounded random arguments?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a function that will write to a mocked kinesis stream and fail on the fourth call. The called with value is intentionally a bounded random variable and therefor we want to assert that the value produced is in the bounds.

```
@patch('time.sleep', return_value=None)
def test_backoff_called_with_on_failure(patched_sleep):
    with batch_writer.KinesisStreamBatchWriter(
             "bad",
             "ok", 
             dead_letters=_one_dead_letter) as batch:
        batch._put_records = _fake_put_records_fail_half
        for i in range(0, 4):
            batch.queue_record({'i': i})

# Add Assert
```

I want to test that time.sleep is called with a random number greater than a floor but less than a ceiling.

How can I assert this condition since `mock.called_with` expects a single deterministic value?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to use the `mock.call_args_list` attribute to get the original arguments and then do comparisons between primitives

```
@patch('time.sleep', return_value=None)
def test_backoff_called_on_failure(patched_sleep):
    with batch_writer.KinesisStreamBatchWriter("bad", "ok", dead_letters=_one_dead_letter) as batch:
        batch._put_records = _fake_put_records_fail_half
        for i in range(0, 4):
            batch.queue_record({'i': i})

    # Begin direct comparison code
    assert len(patched_sleep.call_args_list) > 1
    for index, arguments in enumerate(patched_sleep.call_args_list):
        actual_call_value = arguments[0][0] # Unpack the tuple structure
        assert actual_call_value >= math.pow(
            batch_writer.INITIAL_BACKOFF_TIME,
            index)
```